# Can this jQuery be modified to run faster?

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer

This following jQuery `each` function is causing IE8 to present a "Stop running script? .. A script on this page is causing your browser to run slowly.." message.

```
$('.expand-collapse-icon').each(function() {
    var dupId = $(this).parent('td').attr('duplicate-id');

    var len = $(".results-table tr")
        .filter(":not(:first)")
        .filter(":has(.hidden-row[duplicate-id='" + dupId + "'])").length;

    if (len <= 0) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent('td').css('padding-left', '15px');
    }
});
```

Basically, I have a number of visible rows (about 92) which have associated hidden rows. The rows are associated by `duplicate-id` Each visible row has an `expand-collapse-icon` in the first `<td>`. If you click the icon it will display the hidden rows. If the visible row has no associated hidden rows, I don't want to show the icon.

Ideally I could prevent the page from displaying the icon server-side if there's no associated rows, but there are dragons lurking in the code.

Is there any obvious way that I could speed this up?

Comment: When does this code run? On document ready? Could you post some html as example?

Answer (score 3):

One thing for sure is to get rid of multiple $(this) - "cache" this statement value at the beginning of your function. For example:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Now your script wraps the same object in jQuery 3 times for each iteration - messy!

Other thing that comes to my mind - in general, the ***.each* method is slow**, significantly slower than just simply iterating through result of $(".some-selector-example"). **EDIT**: I've found article [10 ways to instantly increase jQuery performance](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/), while it's pretty old now (it's from 2009), most (if not all) of the tips are still recommended to use. Take especially closer look at the chart showing performance of *.each* method compared to regular loop over the same collection of data.

One last thing is probably the most performance-killing issue of your script - the *len = $(".results-table tr").filter(":not(:first)")* select. What you can do is to at least keep the result of that part of the select (keep this variable outside of function you are iterating in):

```
var cached_trs = $(".results-table tr").filter(":not(:first)");
```

Then in function you're iterating in operate with filter on you can do:

```
var len = cached_trs.filter(":has(.hidden-row[duplicate-id='" + dupId + "'])").length
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Here I have cached most of the repetitive element fetches, avoided filtering of rows by `.hiddne-row` class and search only once and then just filtering by attribute inside the loop which is a major improvement because attribute fetces are mostly slower comared to others. Use `:gt(0)` instead of `:not(:first)' that too only once outside the loop.

```
var $this, $parent, dupId, len ;

//This line will get all the rows from .resutls-table 
//filtered by ":not(:first):has(.hidden-row)"
//That way you dont have to search for trs and filter it everytime in the loop
var $resultsTr = $(".results-table tr.hidden-row:gt(0)");

$('.expand-collapse-icon').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $parent = $this.parent('td');
    dupId = $parent.attr('duplicate-id');

    len = $resultsTr
        .filter("[duplicate-id='" + dupId + "'])").length;

    if (len <= 0) {
        $this.hide();
        $parent.css('padding-left', '15px');
    }
});
```

Comment: @mblase75 - Do you see in the code `$parent` is used at 2 different places so it makes sense to cache it.

Comment: And, as a minor optimization, the class `.results-table` should probably be an ID instead, since it sounds from his description like there's only one such table in the page.

Comment: @mblase75, I didn't specify, but there can be more than 1 table.

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many of the same jQuery selectors.

You can optimize by storing the one you use more than once in a variable.

```
$('.expand-collapse-icon').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent('td');
    var dupId = $parent.attr('duplicate-id');

    var len = $(".results-table tr")
        .filter(":not(:first)")
        .filter(":has(.hidden-row[duplicate-id='" + dupId + "'])").length;

    if (len <= 0) {
        $this.hide();
        $parent.css('padding-left', '15px');
    }

});
```